# Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.compiler.configuration.KotlinJpsPluginSettings resolve this error

Tags: java, arrays, kotlin, plugins, compiler-errors

I wrote a simple java code for a jagged array on Intellij IDEA (2022 Edition) and when I built that, I got an error on the console

Here is the code:

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);

    int [][][]arr=new int[3][2][3];

    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<arr[i].length;j++)
        {
            for(int k=0;k<arr[i][j].length;k++)

            {
                System.out.println("Enter marks of School "+ i +" class "+ j +" Student "+ k);
                arr[i][j][k]=sc.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<arr[i].length;j++)
        {
            for(int k=0;k<arr[i][j].length;k++)

            {
                System.out.println(arr[i][j][k]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

The error I got ->

```
Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.compiler.configuration.KotlinJpsPluginSettings
```